# How to unset time attribute of an iso dateTime date format

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime

I have a date in format 2016-05-24T05:07:57.756Z but i want to unset its time attribute.
e.g- 2016-05-25T00:00:00.000Z.
Please help how can I do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript's Date object has methods like `setHours`, `setMinutes`, etc... read about them at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Thanks, i found solution there.  
dateObj.setUTCHours(0,0,0,0).

Answer (score 1):

You could use [String#slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)

```js
console.log('2016-05-24T05:07:57.756Z'.slice(0, 10) + 'T00:00:00.000Z')
```

For a date as Date object, you may use [Date.UTC()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC)

```
var utcDate = new Date(Date.UTC(96, 11, 1, 0, 0, 0));
```